# prometheus PromQL Grafana query empty string issue

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

This Prometheus PromQL query returns the result

```
((sum by (a,b) (irate (request_total{a=~"xyz.*", b=~"tty", status=~"^[45][0-9][0-9]$"}[10m])))/ (sum by (a,b) (irate (request_total{a=~"xyz.*", b=~"tty",status=~".*"}[10m])))) *100
```

but when I try to filter it more it does not return any result.

```
((sum by (a,b) (irate (request_total{a=~"xyz.*", b=~"tty", id=~".+", status=~"^[45][0-9][0-9]$"}[10m])))/ (sum by (a,b) (irate (request_total{a=~"xyz.*", b=~"tty", id=~".+",status=~".*"}[10m])))) *100
```

Is it something wrong in this `id=~".+"` ?
Though, I have the values in id and they are not populating.
Also, I want to ignore `id=""` with no string but this doesn't return the result.

Comment: Are you sure that left part of second query returns anything?

Comment: Also, `=~".+"` is equivalent to `!=""`

Comment: it seems Prometheus is having some difficulty with "" empty strings.